# Error evalution for Newton-Raphson method

Tags: calculus, approximation

I'm supposed to approximate a solution of an equation using the Newton-Raphson method, knowing one real solution to this , namely $x \approx 0.61803$. $$x^4  + 3x - 2 = 0
$$

Therefore I start by setting up my sequence, getting $$
x_{n + 1}  = \frac{{3x_n ^4  - x_n  + 2}}{{4x_n ^3  + 2}}$$

But how does one find the rank of a term such that the error  is less than $
10^{ - 3} 
$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Newton's method is an iterative solution, you can do it via looping. Look at the relative error. Relative error is defined as:
$$\epsilon_{relative}=\frac{|x_i-x_{i-1}|}{x_i}$$
When this value drops below $10^{-3}$, you are done. Otherwise, keep on iterating. If you want to use the absolute error, just take the top component:
$$\epsilon_{absolute}=|x_i-x_{i-1}|$$